# Why am I getting {statusCode: 400, error: 'Bad Request', message: 'Malicious Path'} when fetching strapi API from my Next.js app

Tags: request, next.js, fetch, strapi, http-status-code-400

When I try to fetch data from strapi API, from my Next.js app I get `{statusCode: 400, error: 'Bad Request', message: 'Malicious Path'}`.
My code looks like this:

```js
import '../styles/globals.css'
import App from "next/app"
import Head from "next/head"
import Link from 'next/link'
import { createContext } from "react";
import { fetchAPI } from "lib/api";
import { getStrapiMedia } from "lib/media"

export const GlobalContext = createContext({})

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const { global } = pageProps;
  console.log(global)
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>{getStrapiMedia(global.siteName)}</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
        <meta name="description" content={getStrapiMedia(global.metaDescription)} />
        <Link rel="shortcut icon" href={getStrapiMedia(global.favicon)} />
      </Head>
      <GlobalContext.Provider value={ global }>
        <Component { ...pageProps } />
      </GlobalContext.Provider>
    </>
  )
}

// get app's properties, ctx = context
MyApp.getInitialProps = async(ctx) => {
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(ctx)
  const global = await fetchAPI("/global");
  return {...appProps, pageProps: { global }}
}
```

Here are functions from api.js and media.js

```js
const API_URL = process.env.API_URL

export function getStrapiURL(path = "") {
  return `${
    API_URL || "http://localhost:1337"
  }${path}`;
}

// Helper to make GET requests to Strapi
export async function fetchAPI(path) {
  const requestUrl = getStrapiURL(path);
  const res = await fetch(requestUrl);
  const data = await res.json();
  return data;
}
```

```js
import { getStrapiURL } from "./api";

export function getStrapiMedia(media) {
  // if media = null return nothing, else return img
  if (typeof media !== "undefined") {
    if (media == null) {
      return "";
    }
    // if media starts with "/" return API_URL + img URL else return img URL
    const imageUrl = media.url.startsWith("/")
      ? getStrapiURL(media.url)
      : media.url;

    return imageUrl;
  }
}
```

It doesn't look like a problem with API as I can fetch the data with postman but not in my App. Fetch would look like this `API_URL/global`.
Any help would be appreciated.
You can find whole code [here](https://github.com/TurniXXD/web-band/tree/strapi-next-client)

Comment: If you log the `requestUrl` to the console in `fetchAPI`, does it return the expected URL? Do you send any additional headers or data when making the request in Postman?

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I was fetching http://API_URL//global instead of http://API_URL/global

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So it turned out I was fetching http://API_URL//global instead of http://API_URL/global. Changing

```js
MyApp.getInitialProps = async(ctx) => {
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(ctx)
  const global = await fetchAPI("/global");
  return {...appProps, pageProps: { global }}
}
```

into

```js
MyApp.getInitialProps = async(ctx) => {
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(ctx)
  const global = await fetchAPI("global");
  return {...appProps, pageProps: { global }}
}
```

solved this issue.